# What laws should I be aware of if I were to start a business scraping profile content from a website and using this content to build another website?

Tags: copyright, internet, gdpr, business, england-and-wales

The idea is to build websites for people (in the UK (at least to start with)) using content that they have uploaded to another website. I will cold-call them, ask them if they would like a website and if they do, I build them one using content that they have uploaded to another website, to save them having to dig out the content again for me.

I understand that cold-calling in the UK is legal, providing that you have vetted the number against the [Telephone Preference Service](https://www.tpsonline.org.uk/) (TPS) and I think they have to be a limited company too.

Although I'm not overly clear on the legalities, my rough understanding is that scraping information from a website is legal, even if against their ToS. Is that correct? I assume there wouldn't be any copyright infringement issues, as the content belongs to the owner of the profile rather than the website that they uploaded it (presumably?)

If I were to scrape contact information from that website in order to build a list of people to contact, would I be breaching any data protection laws by holding onto said contact information that I have collected?

Any advice or pointers on related laws etc that I should be aware of or things I should avoid would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### The laws that make this totally illegal

> ... scraping information from a website is legal, even if against their ToS. Is that correct?

No, that is not correct.

> I assume there wouldn't be any copyright infringement issues, as the content belongs to the owner of the profile rather than the website that they uploaded it (presumably?)

You assume incorrectly. Yes, the owner licensed the material to the website - they didn't licence it to you. Many websites (including this one) allow other users to benefit from that licence - but you're not complying with the ToS, including the license. By copying it without the owner's permission (even from the website) you are breaching their copyright.

> ... would I be breaching any data protection laws by holding onto said contact information that I have collected?

Yes.

The GDPR has 6 lawful basis for collecting personal information: consent, contract, legal obligation, vital interest, public task, or legitimate interests. Your usage is none of those.